# automatically redirect to server webpage without manaully opeaning browser

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I wanted my user device to automatically visit my hostspot (lets say server page. My custom page) webpage after connecting my hotspot. I mean the user dont need to open browser manaully. It will be open automatically making them visit my hotspot page. I wonder if that is possible using my own DNS or something.

I am using kali linux 2.0

Comment: Would a "Click through" captive portal page, that goes to the hotspot page cover your needs?

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS function that you don't have control over. Basically, it works like this:

If the user connects to a wifi network, the OS tries to open an URL in the background. If this gets redirected to a captive portal, the OS knows it should open a browser window with the redirection target.

So, you have to configure a captive portal with your wifi infrastructure.

Comment: So how can I do it? Any suggestion ???